# How to access the position of the previous control point in a curve line in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, splines

This node setup is meant to generate routes for drops of water.
It wraps curve lines on the surface with the geometry proximity node.

| Setup | Result |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I would like each control point (except the first one) to inherit the previous point's X and Y position before the proximity is evaluated.
I tried to use both "field at index" and "transfer attribute" feeding them with index-1 but it's not working:
[image]

Also, if I try with a "sample curve" approach like this.
[image]
I would expect to get the same result as in the first picture, but it's not.

This is the blend file:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This one does it:

[image: node setup]

Control points before:

[image: control points before]

Control points afterwards (take a look at index 1000):

[image: control points afterwards]